# Connect-assetmanager file does not match req.url

Tags: javascript, node.js, minify

No matter what I do, when I enter a js file (`http://localhost:3000/static/js/backbone.js`) in the url, it shows the last file asset manager cached.  So in this case it is showing `jquery.js` even though I entered backbone. Here is the code I am using:

```
var sys = require('sys');
var fs = require('fs');
var Connect = require('connect');
var assetManager = require('connect-assetmanager');
var assetHandler = require('connect-assetmanager-handlers');

var root = __dirname + '/public';

var Server = module.exports = Connect.createServer();

Server.use('/',
    Connect.responseTime()
    , Connect.logger()
);

var assetManagerGroups = {
    'js': {
        'route': /\/static\/js\/.*\.js/
        , 'path': './public/js/'
        , 'dataType': 'javascript'
        , 'files': [
            'jquery.js',
            'backbone.js'
        ]  
    }
};

var assetsManagerMiddleware = assetManager(assetManagerGroups);
Server.use('/'
    , assetsManagerMiddleware
    , Connect.static(root)
);
Server.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that `jquery.js` and `backbone.js` have not been merged into the same `js` file that is returned by your request? This is the [purpose](https://github.com/mape/connect-assetmanager#what-does-it-allow-you-to-do) of `connect-assetmanager`.

Your `assetManagerGroups` definition is basically saying for a request for *any* `.js` file matched on the `/static/js/` route, return a merged and minified version of `jquery.js` and `backbone.js`. The fact you are requesting `backbone.js` is irrelevant.

This is nicely illustrated by the before and after [image](https://github.com/mape/connect-assetmanager#connect-assetmanager) in the README, which shows multiple `jquery` `js` files bundled and returned into a single response to a request for `client.js`.

Comment: Ah yes thank you.  I guess I had not realized it compiles them together and returns them no matter what file is requested. That approach seems really strange to me.  That you would request a file of jquery for your page to have your entire sites js returned that is.  Cool library otherwise.